# Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name with $_POST array data

Tags: php, mysql

I have this form

```
<form action="table_results.php" method="post">
            <?php
            foreach (get_table($_POST['table']) as $row) {  // Fill $row variable with table fields
                ?>
                <input type="text" name="table[ <?php echo $_POST['table'] ?> ][ <?php echo implode($row) // Create table array ?> ]" size="20" >
                <?php
            }
            ?>
            <p><input type="submit" /></p> <!-- Post the table array to table_results.php -->
        </form>
```

get_table(); returns the field names of the specific table

When I use the posted data for the following function

```
function search_db($table, $field, $query) {
$database = new Database();
$database->query( "SELECT * FROM `" . $table . "` WHERE `" . $field . "` = :query" );
$database->bind(":query", $query);
$database->execute();

$result = $database->resultSet();

if (!$result) {
    print 'ERROR';
    die();
} else {
    return $result;
}
}
```

I get the error: "Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name"

I`ve tried to test if the variable contains the right data

```
$array = $_POST['table'];
$table = implode(array_keys($array));
print $table;
```

Outcome: computer

When I input 'computer' in the `$table` variable of - `function search_db('computer', 'id', 1);` - it works fine

When I print the `$table` variable along with 'computer' I get the exact same output.

What could be the cause of my database not recognizing the `$table` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably your problem:

```
name="table[ <?php echo $_POST['table'] ?> ]
```

Note that you are adding spaces before and after the variable in the html array, so when you print the result, it will seem correct, but the real result will be `" computer "` and not `"computer"`. And the `" computer "` table does not exist.

You can use `var_dump()` instead of `print()` to confirm that; it will probably show a length of 10 instead of the 8 for the word `computer`.

So you would need this instead:

```
name="table[<?php echo $_POST['table'] ?>]
```

Apart from that you should really use white-lists for the table- and column names to avoid sql injection and problems like the one you are having now.

Comment: Thanks!! I`m aware of SQL injection and normally use: 
public function query($query) {
  $this->stmt = Database::getDatabase()->getConnection()->prepare($query);
 }
But this is my own personal database and no necessary precautions are needed